# MySQL bigInt vs JSON schema integer

Tags: mysql, json, jsonschema

Want to ask about json schema limit for integer

If we put this on **schema**

```
{
    "data" : {
            "type" : "object",
            "properties":{
                "code":         {"type":"integer"}
            },
            "required":["code"],
            "additionalProperties" : false      
        }
}
```

How many digits is the limit for the **code** on the schema?

What should i put on column type? is it int, smallint, bigint? and how long? is it bigInt(32) or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON-schema` integers are `JSON` integers, and `JSON` integers are not limited in size by [the specification](http://www.json.org/).

Thus, you are not restricting the size by selecting the type `integer`.

Instead, you may use the keywords [`minimum` and `maximum`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#anchor14) which allows you to set boundaries to the `integer` type.

Comment: When I try to update a JSON field in MySql to a large integer number, then I see it is converted to a negative number. For example, if I update the JSON column to {"tax":2147483648} then it will become negative, but if I update to {"tax":2147483647} it works fine. Any idea how to fix this behavior?