# mysqlx connector doesn't work with large integers

Tags: python, mysql

The mysqlx implementation doesn't appear to support large integers. It deduces the type, but doesn't seem to account for overflow.

Looking at the source, I think the only integer types are "v_signed_int" and "v_unsigned_int". The numbers that work are pretty small (32 bit), so I must be doing something wrong, but even if it's a bug, where would I report it?

This is a quick and dirty reproduction

```
import mysqlx

session = mysqlx.get_session({
    'host': 'localhost',
    'port': 33060,
    'user': 'redacted',
    'password': 'redacted',
})

document1 = {
    '_id': 'unique-name-1',
    'small': 888888888,
    'stuff': 'other stuff',
}

document2 = {
    '_id': 'unique-name-2',
    'large': 8888888888,
    'stuff': 'other stuff',
}

try:
    db = session.create_schema('databasename')
except:
    db = session.get_schema('databasename')

try:
    collection = db.create_collection('tablename')
except:
    collection = db.get_collection('tablename')

try:
    collection.add(document1).execute()
    collection.add(document2).execute()
    print('done')
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
```

> <class 'SystemError'>
> <built-in function serialize_message> returned a result with an exception set

select * from tablename;

> doc     {"_id": "unique-name-1", "small": 888888888, "stuff": "other stuff"}
> _id     0x756E697175652D6E616D652D31
> _json_schema {"type": "object"}

sql server 8.0 is configured with

> loose_mysqlx_port=33060

pip freeze | grep mysql

> mysqlclient==2.2.0
> mysql-connector-python==8.0.33

This is as far as I could get in the libraries: Protobuf.mysqlxpb.serialize_message(self._msg) raises the SystemError where self._msg is:

> {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Crud.Insert', 'collection': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Crud.Collection', 'name': b'test', 'schema': b'test_docguardian_documents'}, 'projection': [], 'row': [{'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Crud.Insert.TypedRow', 'field': [{'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Expr', 'type': 7, 'object': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Object', 'fld': [{'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Object.ObjectField', 'key': b'_id', 'value': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Expr', 'type': 2, 'literal': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Datatypes.Scalar', 'type': 8, 'v_string': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Datatypes.Scalar.String', 'value': b'unique-name-1'}}}}, {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Object.ObjectField', 'key': b'small', 'value': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Expr', 'type': 2, 'literal': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Datatypes.Scalar', 'type': 1, 'v_signed_int': 888}}}, {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Object.ObjectField', 'key': b'large', 'value': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Expr', 'type': 2, 'literal': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Datatypes.Scalar', 'type': 1, 'v_signed_int': 888888888888888}}}, {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Object.ObjectField', 'key': b'stuff', 'value': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Expr.Expr', 'type': 2, 'literal': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Datatypes.Scalar', 'type': 8, 'v_string': {'_mysqlxpb_type_name': 'Mysqlx.Datatypes.Scalar.String', 'value': b'other stuff'}}}}]}}]}], 'args': [], 'data_model': 1, 'upsert': False}

Comment: This is related to this question (IMHO): [MySQL bigInt vs JSON schema integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526024/mysql-bigint-vs-json-schema-integer)

Comment: It might be solved here: [Handle bigint and boolean casts in mysql json unwrapping #25427](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/pull/25427), but I do not have a clue in which version this is.

Comment: mysql supports a "no-sql" type table, where the types are deduced, but apparently not correctly. Those links are for mysql as a relational database with defined types.

Comment: nevermind, looks like a mysql bug, filed a report at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=111608